# Illustrator Image trace doesn't appear in a saved PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, image-trace

I have Illustrator CC 15 and I'm trying to image trace this panther sketch. When I do this it comes out how I want then I save as a PDF so I can email it. But when I open the PDF It just shows up as a blank doc. How can I make sure the image trace shows in the saved PDF?

Answer (score 3):

After you apply the trace options, select 'Object → Expand → Ok'. This will permanently convert the trace to vector art and should help with your PDF issue.